# How to know if the most recent article

Tags: conditional-content, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I would like to know how to know if the next article is the most recent ?
And if is not the most recent, dont' show the content (The right arrow and "Article suivant") please,

Here is my current code :

For next :

```
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $next_post->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $next_post->post_title ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For previous :

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>"><?php echo $prev_post->post_title ?></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

[image]

Thank you every one !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like WordPress does not support this out of the box. However, you can get the most recent post via [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), and then check against the result from there.

Here I am using [`array_shift()`](https://php.net/array_shift) to turn the array containing one post into the post itself.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$most_recent_post = array_shift(wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A ));

$next_post = get_next_post();
if (!empty( $next_post )) {
    // is the next post the most recent post?
    if ($most_recent_post['ID'] === $next_post->ID) {
        // next post is most recent post
    } else {
        // next post is not most recent post
    }
}
```

Comment: and in the :  if ($most_recent_post['ID'] === $next_post->ID) { i said the right container display none ?

Comment: I do not know your code. But yes, inside the `if` put the code that is going to be executed, if it is the most recent post

Comment: and what is for get previous post please ?

Comment: You can use [`get_previous_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) for that instead